# MVC 4 CKEditor inline editor does not show toolbar

Tags: c#, jquery, html, asp.net-mvc, ckeditor

Im building MVC 4 with custom CMS right now and im using CKEditor to edit the page. I have a problem with the inline editor. I assign my divs into  as i read on the CKEditor documentation, it should auto-convert the divs into CKEditor with toolbar in it (i have seen the [demo](http://sdk.ckeditor.com/samples/inline.html)).

But every time i click my divs with paragraph or list or anything, the cursor did blink and i can edit the text, but there is no toolbar being displayed.

I did not change the config.js. I tried with simple code but its not working. Please help...

Tried with this code:

```
<div contenteditable="true" id="editor1">
    <p>EDIT ME!</p>
</div>
```

Cant edit it.

Comment: note i tried CKEDITOR.inline('#editor1'); but still doesnt work

Answer (score 0):

Try below code:

```
$('.editor1').click(function() {
  var name;
  for(name in CKEDITOR.instances) {
      var instance = CKEDITOR.instances[name];
      if(this && this == instance.element.$) {
        return;
    }
}
$(this).attr('contenteditable', true);
CKEDITOR.inline(this);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Apparently the CKEditor i have right now in my MVC 4 application was installed from nugget package. The installed plugin does not have the functionality to do inline editing.

So the solution is to install manually from [ckeditor.com](http://ckeditor.com). Unpack the downloaded zip file, then copy to script folder on the project. Choose "Show All Files" from solution explorer, then right click the ckeditor folder and choose "Include in project".